# How is the notation $\frac{d}{dx} (f^3)(1)$ interpreted?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> How is the following notation interpreted? 
>   $$\frac{d}{dx} (f^3)(1)$$

Does this evaluate to $3\cdot f(1)^2\cdot f'(1) $, or is it simply the derivative of a constant and equal to 0?

Comment: Where did you get it from? That notation looks very strange.

Comment: It was in my textbook

Comment: Honestly, it depends on the context...the $3$ could mean the third derivative, or the function cubed.

Comment: From the context it definitely can't mean the third derivative

Comment: In that case, I'd cautiously vouch for your evaluation.

Comment: @Rushabh Usually the third derivative would be denoted $f^{(3)}$ instead, no?

Comment: I consider this notation as really clean and unambiguous! It is as you’ve written in the first place, the derivative of $f^3$ evaluated in $1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd say it probably means the derivative of the function $f$ (whatever that function happens to be) cubed evaluated at $1$. And I'd also suggest that it would probably be better to denote $f$ as $f(x)$:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}(f^3)(1) = 3\cdot [f(x)]^2\cdot f'(x)\vert_{x=1}=3\cdot [f(1)]^2\cdot f'(1)
$$